# IOS deployment error [PAClient Error] E0776 when packaging ipa file

Tags: delphi

I'm receiving following error when I deploy iOS 64bit application.
Getting this error when creating ipa package.

> c:\program files (x86)\embarcadero\studio\21.0\bin\CodeGear.Deployment.targets(742,5): error : E0776 2021-07-31 15:39:32.570 xcodebuild[5723:254826] [MT] IDEDistribution: -[IDEDistributionLogging _createLoggingBundleAtPath:]: Created bundle at path '/var/folders/gh/6js_t90x187364mrz6ptgtjw0000gn/T/gliglibrowser_2021-07-31_15-39-32.569.xcdistributionlogs'.
> c:\program files (x86)\embarcadero\studio\21.0\bin\CodeGear.Deployment.targets(742,5): error : E0776 Exported gliglibrowser to: /Users/kochin/PAServer/scratch-dir/imsdev-MacOS/gliglibrowser.archive/temp
> c:\program files (x86)\embarcadero\studio\21.0\bin\CodeGear.Deployment.targets(742,5): error : E0776 ** EXPORT SUCCEEDED **

Any idea?

Comment: Delphi 10.4 Community Edition

Comment: More than likely you have invalid characters in your CFBundleIdentifier value in the Version Info section of Project Options

Comment: I think CFBundleIdentifier is not wrong because I could ipa package of same project with Delphi 10.3.
Thank you,

Comment: Do you have any other projects that you're able to create an IPA for, with Delphi 10.4.2?

Comment: Now I tried to create simple project.  I could deploy ipa file.

Comment: Does your simple project have the same value for CFBundleIdentifier as the one that does not work? If not, try changing only that value

Comment: Same CFBundleIdentifier.

I did "https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-29692" on Delphi 10.3 and I guess this is bad.
How can I rollback this?

Thanks.

Comment: What exactly did you do? That report contains a *lot* of comments

Answer (score 0):

It was resolved, I removed customized info.plist file.